# What controls the open circuit voltage of a DC boost converter

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, boost

I built a 2 stage cascaded DC to DC converter to boost 12V to 400V. the issue is that my open circuit voltage of both stages is always 260V regardless of the input voltage and duty cycle of the PWM. My question is how can I increase the open circuit voltage since changing the duty cycle and increasing the input voltage doesn't change the open circuit output voltage?Also what can I do to keep the voltage at a 400V because when I connect a load the output voltage drops?

Comment: Agree with the answer below that a flyback is probably the better solution (but you don't say how much output power you need.)  If you want to know why your particular scheme isn't working, a schematic and more details will be necessary.

Comment: I used a normal dc boost scheme with a normal inductor.  I need 800w output power

Comment: Ah, OK, a flyback is not suitable for 800W.  If you were using a "normal" dc boost scheme with a "normal" inductor, you would expect it to behave "normally" and the output voltage should vary with the duty cycle (until you approach the max duty cycle for a boost).  Since it doesn't, we can't help you without a schematic and specifics.  For 800W you might look at a PSFB or something like that if efficiency is important to you.

Comment: _"My question is how can I increase the open circuit voltage"_ - you can do it by designing the circuit properly instead of just throwing parts at it and expecting it to work. Since you haven't told us any more than that, we can't tell what you need to do to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer is, in theory, the output inductance vs. the load capacitance (ignore resistance for now.) The bigger the inductor, the more energy it will dump into the capacitor. Likewise, the smaller the capacitor, the more voltage the output will achieve.

As you add a load, this will drop the achieved voltage.

There could also be some unexpected losses including insulation leakage in the inductor, dielectric leakage through the output capacitor, or other parasitic paths like air discharge.

Try isolating each stage. It could be that you have a breakdown happening in the second stage.

But... your circuit would be better served by using a flyback topology (basically, adding a transformer step-up + inverter.) This will achieve a lower impedance on the output.

More here: [https://www.dsce.fee.unicamp.br/~antenor/pdffiles/High_Step_Up_Converters_Part_I.pdf](https://www.dsce.fee.unicamp.br/%7Eantenor/pdffiles/High_Step_Up_Converters_Part_I.pdf)

Here too: https://www.dos4ever.com/flyback/flyback.html

Comment: I isolated the stages and each stage on it's own(not cascaded) gives and output of 260V (open circuit)

Comment: It's likely limited by a component breaking down (likely the output capacitor.) Given that you want to make 800W, your approach isn't really going to work - you need to engineer a flyback with an appropriate transformer and with components rated for your voltage. Not to mention, safety approvals required for such a device.